# Windows 2012 R2 Server network fails intermittently

Tags: networking, ping, nic, windows-server-2012-r2

I have 2 windows 2012 R2 servers in a production environment. Both are VM's and configured same with the ip address as different. I haven't recieved alert of any kind of network failure for one machine. But second machine fails intermittently.

When I try to connect through rdp, it never connects. No pinging too.. But telnet to 3389 works perfectly. I login to that machine through console, and looked the network adapter settings and I could find no change in already configured settings, but I could find an exclamation mark near to the network icon in the taskbar.

Tried troubleshooting and the result was 
"your computer appears to be correctly configured but the device or resource (www.microsoft.com) is not responding"

When I disable and then re-enable the network interface card, then it will work fine. I can take RDP as well as pinging works perfect.

Googled and found [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/your-computer-appears-to-be-correctly-configured/6f15220c-1dda-4a49-b730-68a75ba447e7) post, but when I checked, no updates have been installed in that server. Have anyone experienced this kind of issue yet??

Any help would be really appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the VMs are running in a Hyper-V environment (on server 2012 R2)?

Depending on what nics your host is using, and how you've configured them, this is a known issue.

See more details here:

http://www.hyper-v.nu/archives/mvaneijk/2013/11/vnics-and-vms-loose-connectivity-at-random-on-windows-server-2012-r2/

Comment: Sorry.. It is not... It is in VMWare Environment..

Comment: Usually you have two NIC types to choose from in VMware. Which one are you using? I've seen similar issues, when using the legacy E1000 adapter. Try to switch to the VMXNET3 adapter instead. Make sure to update the vmtools on your guest first. See more info here: http://www.vmwarebits.com/content/how-to-change-network-adapter-to-vmxnet3-for-windows-guest

Comment: Great...I think you are right... Anyway I will have a check and if it is correct...Will mark your answer correct..Thanks...

But one question too..

This machine is up now. So, if I have to change the adapter type, I believe it must be shut down. Also, can I connect to same network label and give this same static IP? Any other precautions to be taken?

Comment: Imagine it was a physical machine, and the network adapter somehow broke, so you had to replace it - it's basically the same operation you are doing. - So yes, you can connect to the same network label and reuse the static IP. I'd uninstall the E1000 from the OS, before you shut it down and remove the adapter. This way the OS will look at it, like the card was never there.